# Bibliography entry for a paper presented to a workshop

Tags: latex

I'm using bibtex to create a bibliography with xelatex.

I have to cite a paper presented to a workshop, but not published on a book or proceedings.

What @misc fields can I use?

Comment: Fran - you may get a better answer over at [Tex.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), although I think this is possibly on-topic here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the @unpublished record in BiBTeX to reference an unpublished article/paper.  And, although you can get a better answer at [Tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) as Fran said, it is more specific to technical questions relating to TeX/LaTeX/XeLaTeX/etc. rather than writing style.  Ultimately, how you cite the unpublished paper will depend on your field of study and/or what bibliography style you use.

Answer (score 1):

Who are the participants? If you are giving it to a professional group- take a look at papers published by professionals in this group. THAT is what they will expect and appreciate. "We" hold others to the same "standards" we follow.